# ld returned 1 exit status(library docxfactory)

Tags: c++, mingw, docx

Error is displayed when compiling - "ld returned 1 exit status" 
Error is displayed when compiling - "ld returned 1 exit status" 
Error is displayed when compiling - "ld returned 1 exit status"

[image]

[image]

```
  #include "WordProcessingMerger.h"
    #include <exception>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <ctime>
    using namespace DocxFactory;
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
    try
    {
    WordProcessingMerger& l_merger =
    WordProcessingMerger::getInstance();
    time_t l_start = clock();
    l_merger.load(
    "/opt/DocxFactory/exercises/templates/special_fields.dfw");
    l_merger.setClipboardValue("Account", "Account", "12345678901");
    l_merger.setClipboardValue("Account", "Active", "no");
    l_merger.setClipboardValue("Account", "CustomerPic",
    "/opt/DocxFactory/exercises/images/customer1.png");
    l_merger.setClipboardValue("Account", "Comments",
    "<h3>An unordered list:</h3>"
    "<ul>"
    "<li>List

 item</li>"
"<li>List item</li>"
"<li>List item</li>"
"</ul>");
l_merger.paste("Account");
l_merger.save("/tmp/special_fields.docx");
cout<< "Completed (in "
<< (double) (clock() - l_start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC
<< " seconds)."
<< endl;
}
catch (const exception& p_exception)
{
cout << p_exception.what() << endl;
}
}
```

Comment: And where is the code?

Comment: Post code as code please.

Comment: @Raw N Done....

Comment: @Maroš Beťko  Done...

Comment: @SVD102 Post code as formatted text not as image.

Comment: @Raw N Готово. Вставил код.

Comment: @SVD102 English please. And [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What is inside `WordProcessingMerger.h`?

Comment: @Raw N  http://docxfactory.com/tutorial/

Comment: @SVD102 Post code as code, don't link to it. Please read [the help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help) on dos and donts.

Comment: @Raw N I use - IDE: CodeLite, Compiler: MinGW. OS Windows. 
In the project settings all have in tutorial.

Comment: @Raw N Вы мне можете помочь или нет?

Answer (score 2):

```
ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is one of the common linker errors.. I am not sure your error is this one but I am sharing because I faced this once while using "G++".. It can occur if you have more then one ".cpp" file (for example: main.cpp, functions.cpp, etc.) and you are trying to compile only "main.cpp" and not others. The compiler will give error because it is unable to link to other files.

[image]

I was only trying to compile "main.cpp and not another ".cpp" file which had the functions defined on it so compiler was giving linker error (**ld returned 1 exit status**)..

The right command is to write all the ".cpp" files for compilation

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error in your first picture says that ld.exe - that is, your linker - cannot find the file DocxFactory.lib.

You need to check that such a file actually exists in your D:\DocxFactory\lib directory.  If it does not, then you need to either place a copy of DocxFactory.lib file in that directory or modify where ld is looking for DocxFactory.lib.

Comment: DocxFactory.lib находится в в D:\DocxFactory\lib, но почему то ее не может найти.

Comment: I finally saw your comment about using MinGW.  Are you following the directions from tutorial_cpp.pdf on the DocxFactory website?  If so, I might recommend reading through the Linux installation portion of the document (page 4 through 5).

Comment: Да, но я использую для Windows OC.

Comment: MinGW is a set of Linux utilities that have been ported to Windows.  The Windows directions are for Visual Studio.  The Linux directions are for g++, which is the compiler you are using.  You really should look at pages 4-5 of their tutorial PDF.

Comment: Additionally, try linking against "-llibDocxFactory" instead of "-lDocxFactory.lib".  As I said, g++ is a Linux compiler, so I am not sure it will play nicely with Windows .lib files.